# ionic 4 iOS app stuck at splash screen on iOS 13+

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic4, ios13

config.xml

```xml
<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.leo9.gameofplan" version="0.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Game Of Plan</name>
    <description>The Game of Plan app is designed to: Capture your Thoughts and Feelings and convert it into Tangible Action Plan.</description>
    <author email="info@leo9studio.com" href="https://leo9studio.com/">Le9studio Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
    <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-secure-storage" spec="^3.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.2" />
</widget>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Game of Plan</title>

  <base href="." />

  <meta name="viewport"
    content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />


  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

here i attache my config.xml and index.html file.

my app is stuck at splash screen in ios13+ devices. for that reasons the app is rejected for publish for app store. i tried many thing to resolve this error. degrade splash screen plugin that wont work, also added some splash screen related config line into config.xml that also wont work.

what should be the solution?

Comment: Any Error Output in the Console?

Comment: not able to open console in safari. what should be the reason these is my second update, first time its was working properly. @EinfachHans

Comment: And in xcode? Any Logs there?

Comment: 2020-03-03 23:46:31.207075+0530 Game Of Plan[1066:13222] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
2020-03-03 23:46:31.208688+0530 Game Of Plan[1066:13222] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-03-03 23:46:31.315418+0530 Game Of Plan[1066:13222] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.312090ms
2020-03-03 23:46:31.315861+0530 Game Of Plan[1066:13222] CDVPlugin class CDVUIInAppBrowser (pluginName: uiinappbrowser) does not exist.

@EinfachHans

Comment: Looks like you are using the InAppBrowser with UI WebView. This is not a good idea, because the UIWebView is deprecated. But the Class seems to not exist. You have the Plugin installed right? Which cordova-ios Version are you using?

Comment: yes, thanks for the replay. the issue with webview. some how able to resolve it, but getting now error, when integrating google calender API with iso app. its working fine in android app but not working ios app. object is undefined when trying to add gapi in ios app @EinfachHans you have any idea about.

Comment: I'm currently working on this... so I will let you know the answer once I have it. One thing I know for sure... if you remove "<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />", it will start working again. This has something to do with the UIWebView removal.

Answer (score 0):

Yu should add the following code inside your `<platform name="ios">` tag:

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
   <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Taken from here: https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Cordova splashscreen but looking at your `config.xml` content I see that you have a duplicate `SplashScreenDelay` preference, one has a value of `30000`, the equivalent of 30 seconds and the other has a value of `10000`, this can be the reason behind the problem.
 I would remove the duplicate preference and set the time value to 5000 (5 seconds), I would also add `AutoHideSplashScreen` preference and set it to `false`, then add the a timer in the `deviceready` event handler:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 5000);
}
```

It should be explained in [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#splashscreenhide). Check [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#configxml) too.

I hope this helps.